# How to set selected value in each row in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using ng-repeate in my table for building rows.
In each row i have select. In each select i want to select one of the options according to my $scope.vehicles.

This is an HTML:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <div id="vehicleDetails">
        <table id="tblVehicles">
            <tr>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>Model</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="vehiclesRepeat" ng-repeat="vehicle in vehicles">
                <td>{{vehicle.PlateID}}</td>
                <td>
                    <select required ng-model="vehicles.ModelID" id="vehicleModel" class="txtPersonalDetails" ng-options="m.description for m in models" >
                        <option value="">Select Value</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is JS:

```
angular.module('MyApp',[])
            .controller('MyController',function($scope) {

                $scope.vehicles=[{"PlateID":"55533322","ModelDescription":"OPEL","ColorDescription":"blue","ModelID":194,"ColorID":13},{"PlateID":"66688822","ModelDescription":"Mercedes","ColorDescription":"blue","ModelID":238,"ColorID":13}];

                $scope.models=[{"iD":35,"description":"BMV"},{"iD":193,"description":""},{"iD":194,"description":"OPEL"},{"iD":214,"description":"Toyota"},{"iD":215,"description":"Honda"},{"iD":238,"description":"Mercedes"},{"iD":260,"description":"Houndai"}];
                });
```

I build the dropdowns but i can not set selected value in each dropdown.
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ndprdffa/
Does somebody can help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use this

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <div id="vehicleDetails">
        <table id="tblVehicles">
            <tr>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>Model</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="vehiclesRepeat" ng-repeat="vehicle in vehicles">
                <td>{{vehicle.PlateID}}</td>
                <td>
                    <select required ng-model="vehicle.ModelDescription" id="vehicleModel" class="txtPersonalDetails" ng-options="m.description as m.description for m in models" >

                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please refer the fiddle "https://jsfiddle.net/ndprdffa/1/".

**Explaination**

As the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) explains, when you use an expression such as

```
label for value in array
```

what is displayed in the select box is `label`, and what is bound to the ngModel is `value`. So, in your expression:

`ng-model="vehicle.ModelDescription"`

```
 ng-options="m.description for m in models"
```

`m`is one of the objects in the array of `models`. And if you want the object  to be the one selected in the select box, your ngModel should be a reference to this object not only the value

Or, if you want the ngModel to contain the string value of `vehicle.ModelDescription`and not the object containing this value, the expression should be

```
ng-options="m.description as m.description for m in models"
```

Comment: You are welcome!! :-) Please do accept if find useful.